# Insert a comment using the YouTube API and Alamofire

Tags: swift, youtube-api, alamofire, youtube-data-api

I'm confused on how to insert a comment using the YouTube API. I'm fairly new to using APIs, so I don't quite get what they are saying to do in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert).

I've authenticated the user using [Google Sign-In for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) with the scope

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"
```

which is required to insert a comment. But now, I have to actually insert the comment and (like I've said) I don't understand how to do that because I have to provide a resource in the request body. I'm using Alamofire for the request and Swift 4 as my language.

Comment: Did you try this lib? https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest

Comment: In the sample project they add a comment, here: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/b8a4d0b269beb822f8af7057cf03cc48bb82c561/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m#L691

Comment: @BencePattogato Do you know if there is one in Swift? I don't understand objective c lol

Comment: @JacobCavin You can use Objective-C libraries from Swift without having to know Objective-C. Search for "bridging header". It's easy to use.

Comment: @Moritz It doesn't look as if this code actually has the ability to insert a comment. The function that Bence lead me to is actually just updating a video's thumbnail.

Comment: @BencePattogato It looks like they are not inserting a comment, but actually just updating the thumbnail for a video

Comment: I found the wrapper: namely `GTLRYouTubeQuery_CommentsInsert `. See: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/b8a4d0b269beb822f8af7057cf03cc48bb82c561/Source/GeneratedServices/YouTube/GTLRYouTubeQuery.m#L493

Comment: @JacobCavin have you written any code so far, for sending API call to insert comment?

Comment: @Aamir I don't understand how to do it. It says that I need to add data to the Request body (as seen in the documentation I was talking about), but I don't know how to do that. Like I said, I'm very new to using APIs. Thanks for helping me. I've been trying to figure this out for a while, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw in your other post ([Google API - Invalid Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50567322/1433612)) you know how to make an authenticated `Alamofire` request. Now you need to build a proper parameters dictionary to meet the API requirements. I looked into the Youtube Data API guide.

**This is the example of a JSON body provided in the documentation for adding a comment:**

```
{
  "snippet": {
   "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
   "topLevelComment": {
    "snippet": {
      "textOriginal": "This video is awesome!"
    }
   },
   "videoId": "MILSirUni5E"
  }
 }
```

**Let's build a parameters dictionary based on the above example, it is a nested dictionary:**

```
let commentParams: Parameters = ["textOriginal": "This video is awesome!"]
let snippetParams: Parameters = ["snippet": commentParams]
let topLevelSnippet: Parameters = [
        "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
        "topLevelComment": snippetParams,
        "videoId": "MILSirUni5E"]

let allParams: Parameters = ["snippet": topLevelSnippet]
```

**Then create your headers, your request and pass the parameters to the request**

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
// As API requires "part" is added as url parameter
let path = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet"
let request = Alamofire.request(path, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: allParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

You should check which parameters are mandatory and which ones are not, but the idea is to build a proper parameters dictionary based on their requirements.

Comment: Thank you for answering, yet again. You've been the best person I've met on Stack Overflow. I'm getting the error: `FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))` Any ideas?

Comment: This often happens when the response is not a valid json. Some services throw unreadable errors, but I doubt Google would give such response. Are you using some kind of object mapper made for Alamofire such as SwiftyJSON?  It also can happen when a wrong url is called and the service doesn’t know what the request means, thus no proper response. I will check at home if the url is correct again.

Comment: Thank you. I copied your code exactly except I changed the channelId and videoId. I am using Alamofire

Comment: @JacobCavin I have corrected the url. It was not necessary to include `insert` in the url, that is implied by the HTTP method (post). You can read in the docs about the difference between `comments` and `commentThreads` methods and decide which one is relevant to you. You should be getting some kind of response from google now.

Comment: Thanks again. Haha. I keep on saying that. I'm getting an error from Google, now. Thanks for being so patient. `SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 400;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = "youtube.commentThread";
                location = "body.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal";
                locationType = other;
                message = "Comments cannot be empty.";
                reason = commentTextRequired;
            }
        );
        message = "Comments cannot be empty.";
    };
}`

Comment: Not sure what's wrong here, the error states that `textOriginal` has no value, but my example includes a string "This video is awesome!". Are you sure you've copied the dictionary correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171936/discussion-between-jacob-cavin-and-au-ris).

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of `"topLevelComment": toplevelCommetParams,` in the `topLevelSnippet` parameter, I needed to have `"topLevelComment": snippetParams,`

Comment: My bad, I missed that one. Built the dictionary without testing it. I accepted your edit. But glad that finally it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: I am facing same issue. How & where Can I get "Bearer \(token)" ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead build your parameter dictionary like this:

```
        let allParams: [String: Any] = [
            "snippet" : [
                "channelId" : "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
                "topLevelComment" : [
                    "snippet" : [
                        "textOriginal" : "this video is awesome",
                    ],
                    "videoId" : "MILSirUni5E",
                ]
             ]
        ]
```