# Google API - Invalid Credentials

Tags: swift, oauth, google-api, youtube-api, google-signin

I am trying to make an iOS app where a user can rate a YouTube video using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate). To do this, the user has to be authenticated. So, I used Google's [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) to authenticate my users. I followed the [implementation guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), and it seems as if the user gets signed in. I can access data from the user such as their profile image, name, etc.

Because I am using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate), I need to add the YouTube scope to Google Sign-In before the user signs in. So, I do that like so...

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]
```

Now whenever a user signs in, it will request access to their YouTube channel.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sign-In page]

It seems as if everything is working perfectly. But, now to rate the YouTube video. You can check out [Google's documentation on how to rate a YouTube video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate), but basically, this is what I have to do.

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate", method: .post, parameters: ["access_token":token, "id":"9T56NNzHE7A","rating":"like"], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            print("\(response)")
        }
```

Now because this requires authentication, the API needs an access token. So (as you can see above) I give the API the access token Google Sign-In gives me. Which is:

```
let token = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.accessToken!
```

But, the request does not work. The response I get is

```
SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Invalid Credentials";
                reason = authError;
            }
        );
        message = "Invalid Credentials";
    };
}
```

I don't understand how the credentials could be invalid if the user signed in only seconds before. If it helps, here is an example of what my access token looks like (don't worry this isn't actually it):

> ve35.LmaIBHsK3dUPNR34rb0fgThwiZj-dNB7k935EhyVK1X8nkgMBmA-_3Hxhys7uk-HEm3ggg-HIgJv83RHXhGNKdVkWn0sEn7XtaWhTbeVjg8hsBK3hK8H1Gx8KzhhaEJGVg

I've been looking all over the internet trying to find an answer to this but to no avail. So I decided to ask. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Any input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I am pretty sure the access token needs to be added to the headers following OAuth2 protocol and not passed as a parameter. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

Comment: I am not an ios dev but you can pass the access toekn as part of the reeust you just add it &access_token=XXX or you send it as an authentication header bearer token.     However the error message makes me think that there is something wrong with the access token you are sending are you 100% sure you have saved the latest and arent using an older one.

Comment: @AuRis kindly note access_token in this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters

Comment: @DaImTo I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @AuRis It seems as if it is a parameter (see developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters). The API is detecting the "access_token" parameter because if it didn't it would be giving me the response "Login Required." But, I am all for adding it to the headers. Do you know how to do this with Alamofire?

Comment: @JacobCavin Alamofire has `HTTPHeaders` typealias which is just a `[String:String]` dictionary, so you can jsut do `let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]` and then pass to Alamofire request.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment: `let request = Alamofire.request(path, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)`

Comment: @AuRis It worked! Thank you so much! I've been working on this for the longest time. It's crazy that the solution was so simple haha! Would you like to add an answer so I can accept it? Or I can just do it, I just wanted to see if you wanted the points, first.

Comment: @JacobCavin i am glad it worked!

Comment: @AuRis Yeah. Thanks so much! Since you're here, I also want my users to be able to insert a comment for the video. This is a bit different than rating the video because I actually have to provide a resource in the response body, and I don't understand how to do that (Sorry, I'm new to API requests). If it's too much trouble, I'll leave it up to someone else, you've done enough already. But if you want to, here's my question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412254/insert-a-comment-using-the-youtube-api-and-alamofire] (It has a bounty because I'm really desperate haha) Again, thanks a lot

Comment: @JacobCavin I gave an answer to you other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the access token to the headers of your `Alamofire` request instead of passing it as a parameter. As such:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
let request = Alamofire.request(path, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```